# segmented control with container view

Tags: swift

I worked three containers view and linked them to segmented control in the code but the transition works only in the first view and the second

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var parts: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var morelike: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var addlater: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func transction(_ sender: UISegmentedControl)
    {
        if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
        {
            self.addlater.alpha = 0.0
            self.morelike.alpha = 1.0
            self.parts.alpha = 2.0
        }
        else
        {
            self.addlater.alpha = 2.0
            self.morelike.alpha = 1.0
            self.parts.alpha = 0.0
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have one visible view for each segment you can use this in your transition action:

```
switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        self.addlater.alpha = 0.0
        self.morelike.alpha = 0.0
        self.parts.alpha = 1.0
    case 1:
        self.addlater.alpha = 0.0
        self.morelike.alpha = 1.0
        self.parts.alpha = 0.0
    case 2:
        self.addlater.alpha = 1.0
        self.morelike.alpha = 0.0
        self.parts.alpha = 0.0
    default:
        break
}
```

or clearer way:

```
switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        addlater.isHidden = true
        morelike.isHidden = true
        parts.isHidden = false
    case 1:
        addlater.isHidden = true
        morelike.isHidden = false
        parts.isHidden = true
    case 2:
        addlater.isHidden = false
        morelike.isHidden = true
        parts.isHidden = true
    default:
        break
    }
```

Comment: After editing the code it became segmented on the first and third

Comment: @Ab.sh what do you want to achieve with transition?

Comment: I have three container view and each one of them I want to do different content from the other on the same view controller and move them through the segmented control

Comment: Do you want one segment for one visible view? Yes, I want

Comment: Yes, now it's true. Thank you